# Signal handling in shell script with exec and pipe to filter output with grep

Tags: shell, pipe, signals, exec

I'm deploying a containerized application which outputs an enormous amount of useless messages on startup (the same message for about a million times, without any variation). The message cannot be suppressed via configuration of the application and development of the application is outside of my control. This leads to annoying and problematic peaks in the logging infrastructure. Filtering the messages in the logging infrastructure is only possible when viewing logs, not when forwarding them from the container runtime to the logging storage backend though.

So my intention is to suppress this message (`foo bar baz` in the following example) from outside the application using `grep` within the container entrypoint. What I've tried so far is this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail

exec myapp --some parameter | grep --line-buffered -v "foo bar baz"
```

This does not replace PID 1 with `myapp --some parameter` though, causing signals like `SIGTERM` not to be forwarded to the correct process:

```
$> docker exec -it ep-test ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.0  18384  3008 pts/0    Ss+  16:54   0:00 /bin/bash /entrypoint
root         7  0.0  0.0   4540   836 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:00 myapp --some parameter
root         8  0.0  0.0  11472   964 pts/0    S+   16:54   0:00 grep --line-buffered -v "foo bar baz"
root         9  0.0  0.0  34412  2668 pts/1    Rs+  16:54   0:00 ps aux
```

If I reduce the `exec` to `exec myapp --some parameter`, PID 1 is correctly replaced (but the output is not filtered as needed):

```
$> docker exec -it ep-test ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.2  0.0   4540   768 pts/0    Ss+  16:55   0:00 myapp --some parameter
root         7  0.0  0.0  34412  2796 pts/1    Rs+  16:55   0:00 ps aux
```

For a clean shutdown of the application, it is important that `SIGTERM` (and other known signals) are forwarded to `myapp`. To my knowledge, the simplest way to achieve this is by replacing PID 1 with `exec`.

So my question is whether there is an easy way to filter the output of `myapp` with `grep`, while ensuring that signals sent to the container get sent/forwarded to `myapp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a bash named pipe (a fifo) for the grep, so that it doesn't use an ordinary pipe. The syntax `>(cmd)` creates a fifo, runs `cmd` with the fifo as stdin, and is replaced in the command line by the name of the fifo, eg `/dev/fd/63`, so you can then direct the app command's stdout to that fifo with `>`.

```
exec myapp --some parameter > >(grep --line-buffered -v "foo bar baz")
```

Note the space in `> >()`.

Comment: This seems to tick all requirements, though it does not yield any output after sending `SIGTERM` for example. By the duration it takes for the process to exit, it looks like the shutdown is happening gracefully though. Am I right that the second process with `grep` exits immediately upon `SIGTERM` and is there a way to prevent this, e.g. by ignoring signals for this process?

Comment: Apparently, a simple `trap '' SIGTERM` does the job. Thanks a lot!